# React hook useEffect not rerendering after the data is fetched (v18.2.0)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to get data from an api in useEffect. On the inital load the data is not rendered on the page. But the subsequent loads work just fine. I'm not too sure what is going wrong.

These are the states

```
  let audioFileUrl = useSelector((state) => state.fetchAudioFileUrl);
  const [lang, setLang] = React.useState('English');
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.isLoadingDataView);
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.fetchIndividualItem.data);
  const [activeData, setActiveData] = React.useState(data.languages.english.data);
```

And here are the calls being made in useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchdataspinnerstart());
    if (audioAvailable) {
      dispatch(fetchAudioFileUrl(id, CLIENT_CONSTANTS.TYPE));
    } else {
      audioFileUrl = '...';
    }
    dispatch(fetchIndividualItem(id, CLIENT_CONSTANTS.TYPE));
  }, []);
```

The fetchdataspinnersuccess() is triggered by the fetchIndividualItem once it successfully gets the data.

The data is not displayed on the page on the initial load. But everything works fine subsequently.

Edit : Clarifying the exact issue

The data that comes in the state activeData is not being rendered on the initial load. It comes up once any rerender happens on the page. Say I click on any other option on the same page or select a different row in the table it loads perfectly fine.

Here is the action code that is dispatched.

```
export const fetchIndividualItem = (docId, fetchType) => (dispatch) => {
  const id = docId;
  const type = fetchType;
  axios.get(`${baseuri}/sections/${id}?type=${type}`)
    .then((response) => {
      const { data } = response;
      dispatch(fetchindividualdatasuccess(data));
      dispatch(fetchdataspinnersuccess);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorMsg = error.message;
      dispatch(fetchdatafail(errorMsg));
    });
};
```

Comment: So is the issue or problem with something one of these dispatched actions is doing? Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail what the specific issue is and include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code?

Comment: If you are using local component state then (a) the state will be available on the initial render, and (b) it's anti-pattern to duplicate state into local component state, you will need to use a `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency to update the `activeData` state if you insist on state duplication.

Comment: Is the missing `()` at `dispatch(fetchdataspinnersuccess);` relevant ? It should be `dispatch(fetchdataspinnersuccess());`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli  Thanks. that was a minor miss. But that does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, the local state is a requirement as the activeData keeps changing based on the language selected on the UI. But what I'm not sure about is, why it causes an issue on the initial load, and why the next loads work fine. But let me try refactoring the code to directly use the state and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The `useEffect` hook runs after the component has rendered, meaning any side-effect it triggers won't be seen until *at least* the next render cycle. Yes, you should try to update the code to simply reference `data.languages.english.data` directly. Use the `useMemo` hook in lieu of the `useState`/`useEffect` pair if you need to memoize the value.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks. That worked. After I referred the fetched state directly (data) rather than the copied local state(activeData). But I still wonder what would be the workaround if I wanted to use a local state.

Comment: @Shreehari My suggestion was to use the `useMemo` hook instead of a `useState`/`useEffect` pair.